# Fell for crypto Scam, I NEED HELP

Tags: fraud

I think I am being scammed right now - I have researched (too late) about this operation and a lot of stories seem to match what is happening to me right now. They made me pay a 30% fee to withdrawal with my funds in hostage and then said that my account is suspected of money laundering and I would need to pay 6K USDT deposit with 3 days or else they will be "frozen forever". This definitely sounds like some bull.

However, Becent is has no noise around it and has been around since 2015 so I am not sure... Has anyone else had this happen to them by Becent?

The platform looks exactly like other confirmed scams such as Hydefieco..

Comment: This is a scam.

Comment: What can i do to get my funds back?

Comment: @HannahHowell unfortunately, you most likely will be unable to recover your funds. You can report the incident to your local law enforcement, etc. Best of luck.